# Send Gesture to the UIView behind (both should handle touch)

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have an UIView on top of `UISplitViewController` (used "addSubView"). What I wanna do is to let the `UIView` handle the touch and then redirect it to the parent view so it could also handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a work around for what you try to do. You'll have to subclass your topView and implement the following two methods:

The first method will handle your touch for the buttomView

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    CGPoint bottomViewHit = [bottomView convertPoint:point fromView:self];        

    if ([topView pointInside:topViewHit withEvent:event]) {
        //manage your bottomView touch here..
        return bottomView;
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

The second method will handle the topView

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    // manage your touch for topView here...
    [view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for using different language, but this will let me better explain my needs (later i will try to translate). Здравствуйте, Цветелин, спасибо за ваш ответ, но я объясню что мне нужно: верхний слой должен принимать на себя только panGestureRecognizer и tapGestureRecognizer. Нужно это для того, чтобы пользователь мог закрыть SWRevealViewController внутри UISplitViewController, но при этом мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог пользоваться всем, что находится на нижнем слое. Спасибо за вашу помощь.